# Segmentation fault while using const_cast to overload a constant function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, const-cast

I'm having some problems with the `const_cast` function. I created a class `Calorimeter` that consists of a `CaloGrid` and some other stuff. I have to overload the `grid()` function to return the `CaloGrid` belonging to the class `Calorimeter`, however calling the main function returns a segmentation fault.

I know that using `const_cast` is not the best practice, but for this assignment I have to use it. Simply duplicating the code for the `const CaloGrid& grid() const` for the non-constant function would probably work.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this? And what is the point of overloading the function with a `const` copy of the function?

main.cpp

```
/*headers*/
int main() {
// create 2x2 Calorimeter object
Calorimeter C(2,2);
// return the CaloGrid class from this object
C.grid();
// gives segmentation error
}
```

Calorimeter.cpp

```
/*headers*/

// Calorimeter is object with CaloGrid of dimensions nx by ny
Calorimeter::Calorimeter(int nx,int ny){
// initalize the grid and allocate memory
    Cgrid = new CaloGrid(nx,ny);
}

Calorimeter::~Calorimeter(){
// delete memory
    delete Cgrid; 
}

// return the grid
const CaloGrid& Calorimeter::grid() const{
    return *Cgrid;
}

// segmentation error
CaloGrid& Calorimeter::grid(){
    return const_cast<CaloGrid&> (Calorimeter::grid());
}
```

Calorimeter.hh

```
#ifndef CALORIMETER_HH
#define CALORIMETER_HH

class Calorimeter {

public:    // Interface
    Calorimeter(int,int);

    ~Calorimeter();

    const CaloGrid& grid() const;

    CaloGrid& grid();

private:   // Implementation

CaloGrid *Cgrid;

}

#endif
```

Comment: I'd suspect you have been hitting undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
return const_cast<CaloGrid&> (Calorimeter::grid());
```

You are infinitly calling `grid()`.  Since the `grid` function is non const `Calorimeter::grid()` will call the non const version of the function again, which calls the non const  version again which, well, you get the point.

If you want to call the `const` version of the function then you need to cast `this` to `const`.  You can do that with

```
const_cast<const Calorimeter&>(*this)
```

So with that your full code would look like

```
return const_cast<CaloGrid&>(const_cast<const Calorimeter&>(*this).grid());
```

If it doesn't look right it is probably the tears getting in your eyes from the code.

Comment: This did the trick. And I have tears in my eyes, the vagueness of these assignments is insanely frustrating.

Comment: @Roeland: Did your teacher actually say *"use const_cast"* or did he/she say *"add a const overload of the function"*? Chances are you are completely misunderstanding the assignment, and `const_cast` is not the expected solution.

Comment: It said: "Add a function const CaloCell* cell(int x,int y) const. 
Optional: do you need to duplicate the code of the non-const cell() 
function? (Hint: think about using `const_cast<>` and `this`.

Comment: @Rooler: This assignment is insanely well specified. And it's a good one, too, that actually tickles your brain enough to see, if you really understood what you are doing. Granted, though, if your non-const version can call into the const version, there's no need to even have a non-const version to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your class method:

```
CaloGrid& Calorimeter::grid(){
```

What does it do? Well:

```
return const_cast<CaloGrid&> (Calorimeter::grid());
```

It calls `Calorimeter::grid()`, and applies `const_cast` to its return value? What does this `Calorimeter::grid()` do? See above.

The issue of what `const_cast` does, and whether or not it's the right thing to do is irrelevant. This class method calls itself, resulting in infinite recursion, and your program blows quickly, as it runs out of its operating system-allotted stack space.

Although it's not quite clear what you're trying to do here, the answer as to the reason of your segfault is quite simple: infinite recursion.

The recursive call does not invoke the other, overloaded, `const` class method. This is being called from a mutable class method, so it picks the mutable overload, again.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the other posts, you may want to consider writing it this way:

```
#include <memory>

struct CaloGrid {
  CaloGrid(int x, int y) {};
};

class Calorimeter {

public:    // Interface
    Calorimeter(int,int);

    // no destructor - it's not necessary

    const CaloGrid& grid() const;

    CaloGrid& grid();

private:   // Implementation

  // resources managed automatically    
  std::unique_ptr<CaloGrid> Cgrid;
};

// Calorimeter is object with CaloGrid of dimensions nx by ny
Calorimeter::Calorimeter(int nx,int ny)
  : Cgrid { std::make_unique<CaloGrid>(nx, ny) }
{
}

// return the grid
const CaloGrid& Calorimeter::grid() const{
    return *Cgrid;
}

// no error any more
CaloGrid& Calorimeter::grid(){
    return *Cgrid;
}

int main() {
    // create 2x2 Calorimeter object
    // now we can use move-construction
    auto C = Calorimeter(2,2);

    // return the CaloGrid class from this object
    C.grid();
}
```

The raw pointer has been replaced with a smart pointer. This gives us (at least) 2 advantages:

1. Resource management is automated, so we can't forget to delete the `CaloGrid`, or accidentally delete it twice.
2. Calorimeter inherits the copy/move capabilities of the smart pointer (in this case, dangerous unwanted copies are disallowed but we get to keep moves and move-assignments)

Furthermore, although the `grid` method now repeats code, it repeats trivial code. The class has become much easier to both use correctly and maintain.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it was in the original question. CaloGrid is a placeholder structure in this example - it wasn't supplied in the original code.

Comment: Yeah I realise that, just saying I don't see the point of it. At least you improved it with a smart pointer so it doesn't leak and can't break the class's copy semantics :) (insomuch as it prohibits the broken copies from compiling) I wonder whether this improvement and explanation is worth explicitly calling out in the answer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit who knows - maybe it has a mutex in it?

Comment: Mm maybe. I would still delete the "local" copy constructor so as not to rely on inherited protections. But that may just be me

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think that would be a reasonable improvement

Comment: *high-five* \o/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the following

```
CaloGrid & Calorimeter::grid()
{ 
    return const_cast<CaloGrid &>(const_cast<const Calorimeter *>(this)->grid());
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 
}
```

Otherwise the non-constant member function grid is recursively calls itself.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having some problems with the `const_cast` function.

It's an operator, not a function.

> I know that using `const_cast` is not the best practice,

It is bad practice if you design your code's architecture such that `const_cast` cannot be avoided. It can be an acceptable real-life workaround if const correctness **has already been violated elsewhere** (e.g. in libraries you have to use, although well-designed libraries do not suffer from such shortcomings).

> but for this assignment I have to use it.

Says who?

> Simply duplicating the code for the `const CaloGrid& grid()` const for the non-constant function would probably work.

Yes, and it would be best practice. Just do it.

> What am I doing wrong?

You've been a bit too eager to apply the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. This has made you write code which has accidentally caused the infinite recursion problem explained by Sam in the other answer.

> And what is the point of overloading the function with a `const` copy of the function?

The `const` overload allows you to call the function on a `Calorimeter const` object.

It's like [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), just to name a prominent example. Operations like that often come in const/non-const pairs.

You can look up how your compiler implements `std::vector::operator[]`. There's a good chance it will just duplicate the tiny piece of code necessary and *not* use `const_cast` or other tricks.

---

By the way...

It may not be a good idea to have a function like `grid()` in the first place. It practically makes the `private` data member public.